# Query options for getting single value with the specified key in ASP.NET OData Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, odata

When I created OData controller with default "demo" implementation I noticed that there is query options in the method which gets a specific value with a specific Id:

```
    // GET: odata/TestModels(5)
    public IHttpActionResult GetTestModel([FromODataUri] int key, ODataQueryOptions<TestModel> queryOptions)
    {
        // validate the query.
        try
        {
            queryOptions.Validate(_validationSettings);
        }
        catch (ODataException ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }

        //return Ok<TestModel>(testModel);
        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented);
    }
```

I can't find information how to use query options for getting an individual value/ For getting a list of values we can use something like:

```
        var results = queryOptions.ApplyTo(_testModelsRepository.TestModels.AsQueryable());
```

But how to use them for returning a specific value if this method returns specific `TestModel` but not `IQueryable<TestModel>`? And does it make sense to use query options for getting an individual value? Because I didn't find any example on the Internet with using query options for getting a specific value. And if it doesn't make sense then why Visual Studio adds query options to the method for getting a specific value?

Comment: One of possible usage is to specify data that needs to be returned. 'select' and 'expand' methods, so they still can be used in case of just one item, so we can specify properties that we need from that object via OData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can just use [Queryable] attribute in your method, and remove the ODataQueryOptions in parameter, OData will apply this for your result.

Or use SingleResult:

```
SingleResult result = SingleResult.Create(TestModels.AsQueryable());
```